# BLAS sdot operation implementation in MKL library

Tags: math, numeric, blas

I tested the BLAS `sdot` interface for single precise floating point dot operations. I found that the results of Intel MKL library are a little different from that of the BLAS fortran code given in http://netlib.org/blas/. The MKL ones appear more accurate.

I just wonder is there any optimization made by MKL? Or how does MKL implement it to make it more accurate?

Comment: Could you explain how you determined that MKL is more accurate than the reference fortran BLAS for `sdot`?

Comment: I used these two `sdot` in bicgstab solver, it turns out that the MKL one converge much more fast.

Answer (score 1):

Well, since the MKL is especially written by a specific CPU vendor for their own products, I guess they can use a bit more knowledge about the underlying machine than the reference implementation can.

First thoughts may be that they use optimized assembly and always keep the running sum on the x87 80bit floating point stack without rounding it down to 32bit in each iteration. Or maybe they use SSE(2) and compute the whole sum in double precision (which shouldn't make much of a difference for addition and multiplication, performance-wise). Or maybe they use a completely different computation or what black magic machine tricks ever.

The point is that these routines are far more optimized for a specific hardware than the basic reference implementation, but without seeing their implementation we cannot say in which way. The above mentioned ideas are just simple approaches.

Comment: I would guess that an SSE2 implementation with vector registers could perform the dot product using fused FMAD operations in a "tree like" reduction algorithm. That should suffer from much accumulation and intermediate rounding error than a single scalar summation would.

Comment: Thanks very much for your answers! I think the Intel guys must have made a lot optimization on their platform. Thank you!